# Failed assertion: line 5070 pos 12: '<optimized out>': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

After a user successfully logins in and saving the state, I want to hide the login screen and just load the home screen, but I end up with the error

> The following assertion was thrown building
> Navigator-[GlobalObjectKey
> _WidgetsAppState#6686e](dirty, dependencies: [UnmanagedRestorationScope, HeroControllerScope], state:
> NavigatorState#c7e9f(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)):
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 5070 pos 12: '': is not true.

What is the right way of hiding the login screen when the token is still valid, and just load the home screen?

my code

Main.dart

```
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 
       @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'What',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Palette.scaffold,
      ),
      // home: SignIn(),
      routes: {
        //Homepage and being controled by PagesProvider
        '/': (context) => SignIn(),
        'nav': (context) => NavScreen(),
        // add all routes with names here
      },
    );
  }
}
```

my signin.dart

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  MsalMobile msal;
  bool isSignedIn = false;
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MsalMobile.create('assets/auth_config.json', authority).then((client) {
      setState(() {
        msal = client;
      });
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    });
  }

  /// Updates the signed in state

  refreshSignedInStatus() async {
    bool loggedIn = await msal.getSignedIn();
    if (loggedIn) {
      isSignedIn = loggedIn;
      if (isSignedIn) {
        dynamic data = await handleGetAccount();
        dynamic token = await handleGetTokenSilently();
        dynamic result = token;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        sharedPreferences.get("username");
        sharedPreferences.get("token");
        print('access token (truncated): ${result.accessToken}');
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NavScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }
      // Remaining code for navigation
    }
  }

  /// Gets a token silently.
  Future<dynamic> handleGetTokenSilently() async {
    String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT_ID";
    final result = await msal.acquireTokenSilent([SCOPE], authority);
    if (result != null) {
      // print('access token (truncated): ${result.accessToken}');
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      sharedPreferences.setString("token", result.accessToken);
      return result;
    } else {
      print('no access token');
      return null;
    }
  }

  /// Signs a user in
  handleSignIn() async {
    await msal.signIn(null, [SCOPE]).then((result) {
      // ignore: unnecessary_statements
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    }).catchError((exception) {
      if (exception is MsalMobileException) {
        logMsalMobileError(exception);
      } else {
        final ex = exception as Exception;
        print('exception occurred');
        print(ex.toString());
      }
    });
  }

  logMsalMobileError(MsalMobileException exception) {
    print('${exception.errorCode}: ${exception.message}');
    if (exception.innerException != null) {
      print(
          'inner exception = ${exception.innerException.errorCode}: ${exception.innerException.message}');
    }
  }

  /// Signs a user out.
  handleSignOut() async {
    try {
      print('signing out');
      await msal.signOut();
      print('signout done');
      refreshSignedInStatus();
    } on MsalMobileException catch (exception) {
      logMsalMobileError(exception);
    }
  }

  /// Gets the current and prior accounts.
  Future<dynamic> handleGetAccount() async {
    // <-- Replace dynamic with type of currentAccount
    final result = await msal.getAccount();
    if (result.currentAccount != null) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      sharedPreferences.setString("username", result.currentAccount.username);
      //print(result.currentAccount.username);
      return result.currentAccount;
    } else {
      print('no account found');
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    progressDialog  = ProgressDialog(context, type:ProgressDialogType.Normal, isDismissible: false, );
    return MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Image.asset('assets/landing.webp',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  width: 130.0,
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          color: Color(0xffffffff),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.microsoft,
                                color: Color(0xFF01A6F0),
                              ),
                              // Visibility(
                              //   visible: !isSignedIn,
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                              Text(
                                'Sign in',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
                              ),
                              // child: RaisedButton(
                              //   child: Text("Sign In"),
                              //   onPressed: handleSignIn,
                              // ),
                              // ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => {                         
                            progressDialog.show(),
                                handleSignIn(),
                                progressDialog.hide()
                              })),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should Navigate to the homePage only if the login is successful

because Naviagation.Pop is Equal to the Back button and user can do it manually

here is a better approach :

in main.dart  add this :

```
  routes: {
      Homepage and being controled by PagesProvider 

        'nav': (context) => NavScreen(),
        'home': (context) => HomePage(),
         // add all routes with names here 
      },
```

in your refreshSignedInStatus() :

remove this :

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NavScreen(),
          ),
        );
```

add this :

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'nav');
```

Comment: where do I add the SignIn button?

Comment: it depends .. if you are tying to make a Loged in users only app experience  then the login page should be the first thing the new user sees when he opens the app ..

but it you are trying to make it optional then you can add the sign in button at the top or at  a side menu that redirects to login page .. and you should alter the logic and the ui of the app to change depending on the user login status

Comment: login screen it is the first thing the user sees when they launch the app, My question was, when is the route for home and signin called when you define the route on home page? coz after doing it your way I end up with an error `Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.`

Comment: you don't define the rout in home page you define it in the main.dart  in return Material App before  you call your home page .. here is a full example of the code : 

 return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       routes: {
        'splash': (context) => SplashScreen(),
        'home': (context) => HomePage(),
      },
      home: SplashScreen(),
  
    );

Comment: I have shared my Main.dart code, that is giving me error, it can figure out where to go

Comment: you're commenting your home attribute :       // home: SignIn(), and using PagesProvider for it witch is not called  ,, that what causes the problem